# Unary minus operator overload C++ segmentation fault

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I have an object Matrix and I overloaded the unary minus operator and I can't manage to make my program work. If I put the return type as reference it does not allow me to return the object I created inside the function, if I put the return type as Matrix then I get segmentation fault.

in the H file :

```
Matrix operator - () const;
```

in the cpp file:

```
Matrix Matrix::operator - () const
{
  if (isValid==false)//just a validity check
    return *this;

  Matrix mat(*this);//copy ctor

  for (int i=0;i<row;i++)
       for (int j=0;j<col;j++)
          mat.matrix[i][j]=-matrix[i][j];

  return mat;
}
```

I tried many permutations of that (adding const, adding by reference) and nothing seems to work. How do I fix this ?

Comment: The implementation and use would help

Comment: Any use of the minus operator triggers the segmentation fault, and it doesn't even enter the function(tried to cout something). 

I will write it regardless

Comment: You have to put the real code, that method doesn't even has parameters and if it doesnt enter the function put the call site.

Comment: Usually a segmentation fault is caused by buffer overruns or accessing memory outside a range.  Verify that the indices `i` and `j` are within range of the matrix.

Comment: The problem is possibly in your copy constructor or assignment operator (assuming you have one). One of those may be invoked when you return an object.

Answer (score 1):

What follows works without any segmentation faults.  You should minimize your code by removing anything unneccessary, then gradually transform it to the code below, and see at what stage your segmentation fault vanishes.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Matrix {
public:
    Matrix() : isValid(true), row(0), col(0) {}
    Matrix(int r, int c, int val);
    Matrix(const Matrix&);
    Matrix operator - () const; 
private:
    bool isValid;
    int row, col;
    vector<vector<int> > matrix;
};

Matrix::Matrix(int r, int c, int val) : isValid(true), row(r), col(c) {
    matrix.resize(r);
    for (int i=0; i<r; i++)
        matrix[i].resize(c, val);
}

Matrix::Matrix(const Matrix& m) : isValid(true), row(m.row), col(m.col), matrix(m.matrix) {}

Matrix Matrix::operator - () const
{
  if (isValid==false)//just a validity check
    return *this;

  Matrix mat(*this);//copy ctor

  for (int i=0;i<row;i++)
       for (int j=0;j<col;j++)
          mat.matrix[i][j]=-matrix[i][j];

  return mat;
}

main() {
    int r=10, c=5;
    Matrix m(r, c, 1);
    Matrix m1;
    m1 = -m;
}
```